# MX-21 /tmp directory empty on reboot

Tags: tmp

I am using MX-21 and my /tmp directory is getting purged on every reboot. I would like to keep my /tmp for a week, so after some searching the web I modified the /etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf file  and added this line

```
d /tmp  0755 root root 7d
```

and it's is NOT Helping me and the /tmp  directory is still getting
purged. What do I need to do to keep the contents of /tmp for a week?

Comment: Usually `/tmp` is mounted as type tmpfs. That is, a RAM disk. So figure out what is mounting it (`/etc/fstab`?). With that said, why do you need to keep persistent temporary data? That's what `/var/tmp` is for.

Comment: remark: keeping something for a week sounds a lot like you actually want to log sensibly! So, use your systems logging facilities!